# way to disable Hibernate from within gconf-editor so button disappears?

Tags: hibernate

There used to be a way to disable Hibernate from gconf-editor: apps -> gnome-power-manager -> can_hibernate. unticking "can_hibernate" would even remove the hibernate button from the shutdown menu.

This gconf option appears to no longer be present. Is there another way to disable hibernate and simultaneously remove the Hibernate button from the shutdown menu?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open a terminal and run the following command:

   ```
   gksu gedit /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
   ```

   This opens up `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy` for editing.
2. In the `org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate` section, changed the the line `<allow_active>yes</allow_active>` to `<allow_active>no</allow_active>`:

   [image]
3. Restart `indicator-session-service` so for the change to take effect:

   ```
   killall indicator-session-service
   ```

That's it, there should no longer be a *Hibernate* item in the session menu.

[image]

Comment: This is still relevant in 11.10. Thanks so much