# How can I disable screen locking _completely_ in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: screen, lock

We have Ubuntu-clients in our school and our students MUST NOT lock their screen. If they leave, they have to log out.

Unfortunately there is an option to lock screen, so many students do so.

I managed to disable the automatic screen-lock, but I like to disable this completely. 
How can I manage this?

Thank you in advance, 
Jesko

Answer (score 0):

I do not work with Ubuntu 10.04 myself, but found a threat that deals with easily removing the Hibernate button from the logout screen. I assume that removing the "lock screen" option works in the same way.

[way to disable Hibernate from within gconf-editor so button disappears?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50443/way-to-disable-hibernate-from-within-gconf-editor-so-button-disappears)

Maybe someone has a simpler solution, otherwise hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on disabling of lock-screen by following command in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```